# ExpressionEngine Lexer

Tags: ee2

Has anyone tried or succeeded in building an ExpressionEngine Lexer that could be used to build out customized code hinting and coloring?

I haven't seen one out there, but didn't know if I was just overlooking things or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of addons for popular editors to add syntax highlighting and code completion.

Here's some that I'm aware of...

- Coda: http://www.siblify.com/blog/expressionengine_2_syntax_mode_for_coda_2/
- Sublime Text: https://github.com/mrw/ExpressionEngine2-Sublime-Text-Bundle
- Atom: https://atom.io/packages/language-expressionengine

Comment: Thanks. I use Coda now myself with the same add-on, but I have run into more and more people that are using Dreamweaver and/or PHPStorm. I tried coding one up for Dreamweaver, but I was unable to recognize the {} brackets like I would have liked to.